# HDF5 on Fortran what's inappropriate type

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I try write HDF5 file on Fortran. I faced to error.

I wrote example as follows.

```
program ex11

! 宣言

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env 
    use HDF5
    implicit none
    intrinsic max, min

! 

    character(LEN=1), parameter :: dsetname_x = "x" ! dataset for splits
    character(LEN=19), parameter :: output_file_path = "../data/output.hdf5"
    integer, parameter :: ndims = 2

!
    integer :: error
    integer(HID_T) :: file_id
    integer(HID_T) :: dspace
    integer(HID_T) :: dset_id_x
    double precision, dimension(3,3) :: data
    integer(8), dimension(2), parameter :: dims = (/3,3/)
    integer :: i, j

    call h5fcreate_f(output_file_path, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, error)

    do i = 1,3
        do j = 1,3
            data(i,j) = 1.0
        end do
    end do

    call h5screate_simple_f(ndims, dims, dspace, error)

    call h5dcreate_f(file_id, dsetname_x, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, dspace, dset_id_x, error)

    call h5fclose_f(file_id, error)

end program ex11
```

I show error as follows. whats inappropriate type.

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.14.0) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 186 in H5Dcreate2(): unable to synchronously create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to create file
  #001: H5D.c line 134 in H5D__create_api_common(): unable to create dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to create file
  #002: H5VLcallback.c line 1876 in H5VL_dataset_create(): dataset create failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Unable to create file
  #003: H5VLcallback.c line 1841 in H5VL__dataset_create(): dataset create failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Unable to create file
  #004: H5VLnative_dataset.c line 255 in H5VL__native_dataset_create(): not a datatype ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a particular API, you may want to try [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com), a high-level (declarative) language to handle HDF5 files. Your example could be solved as follow using HDFql in Fortran:

```
PROGRAM Example

    USE HDFql
    INTEGER :: state, i, j
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(3, 3) :: data

    ! create an HDF5 file named 'data.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE AND USE FILE ../output/data.h5")

    ! create a dataset named 'x' of type double with two dimensions (size 3x3)
    state = hdfql_execute("CREATE DATASET x AS DOUBLE(3, 3)")

    ! assign values to variable 'data'
    DO i = 1, 3
        DO j = 1, 3
            data(i, j) = 1.0
        END DO
    END DO

    ! register variable 'data' for subsequent use (by HDFql)
    state = hdfql_variable_transient_register(data)

    ! write content of variable 'data' into dataset 'x'
    state = hdfql_execute("INSERT INTO x VALUES FROM MEMORY 0")

    ! close HDF5 file
    state = hdfql_execute("CLOSE FILE")

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: I download HDFql. HDFql is maybe good component. But I think not suitable for me. HDFql has only binary. My test type system is Raspberry Pi 400 X 4.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not initialise the HDF5 runtime with a call to [h5open_f](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/H5_OPEN).

Without that call, variables such as H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F and H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE have meaningless values, resulting in nonsensical HDF5 API requests.